# What is the best practice to send error message in REST?

Tags: rest

I didn't find any guideline regarding the error message in REST.

for example in case of 403 i want to add message like "your account as been disabled"

I found some options:

1. **SOAP-like**: using body not only for models but adding "errorMessage" or other things
2. **Header**: in case of 4xx or 5xx will be an extra header called "errorMessage"
3. **error body**: all calls in case of error has same body model that replace the success body model
4. **status message/reason-phrase**: http near the status code (like 200 or 403) has a text ("ok", "forbidden"), and we can replace with custom string

the last option seams the more REST-like solution, but i don't know if status message can be customized by rule protocol

Comment: "REST" is not a specification...

Comment: The best way is to be consistent in your API about how you return information.

Comment: Use the 'application/problem+json' format to describe further details. This is the standard errror message format. Do not use the status string. It doesn't exist anymore in HTTP/2

Comment: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9457.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long story short [RFC9457](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc9457) suggest solution number 3 with special header "Content-Type: application/problem+json" and standard error body model.

```
POST /purchase HTTP/1.1
Host: store.example.com
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json, application/problem+json

{
  "item": 123456,
  "quantity": 2
}


HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Content-Type: application/problem+json
Content-Language: en

{
 "type": "https://example.com/probs/out-of-credit",
 "title": "You do not have enough credit.",
 "detail": "Your current balance is 30, but that costs 50.",
 "instance": "/account/12345/msgs/abc"
}
```

Thanks to @jeremy-fiel and @evert. To see detailed reasons see @voiceofunreason answer

Answer (score 2):

> What is the best practice to send error message in REST?

See [RFC 9110](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-client-error-4xx):

> Except when responding to a HEAD request, the server SHOULD send a representation containing an explanation of the error situation, and whether it is a temporary or permanent condition

Remember, your canonical example of REST is the world wide web itself.  If you want the human operating the browser to understand that there has been a problem, and what options are available to proceed, you put that information into the response body.

Writing an "API" doesn't change that basic idea (although of course we might be sending the information in a more machine friendly format).

It's not unreasonable that you might *also* include some fields (aka headers) in cases where it makes sense to share information with *general purpose components* that might be used in processing the message.  Which is to say, if you have information to share, and the semantics of that information meets the expectations of one of the [registered](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-fields/http-fields.xhtml) HTTP fields, then by all means include that.

I'd be suspicious of the suggestion to transmit error information via a bespoke header.

---

Using the reason-phrase is not a particularly good choice; see RFC 9112

> A client SHOULD ignore the reason-phrase content because it is not a reliable channel for information

---

> we might be sending the information in a more machine friendly format

[RFC 9457](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc9457) defines [application/problem+json](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc9457); a candidate standardized representation that you might use for explanations of error situations.

The basic idea here is that we have a message schema with some fields that have universally common semantics, combined with the ability to include [extension members](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc9457#name-extension-members) which can be understood be bespoke clients.

Comment: RFC7807 has been updated with [RFC9457](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc9457)

Comment: You are right - I had forgotten.